# Map projections distorted

Tags: c#, projection, godot, gdscript, mercator

I am trying to build geojson shapes in godot and display them, but when trying to do so with Mercator projection, the lines become distorted and I can't find a solution to this problem. What I think I need is some kind of scaling factor that I am missing and therefor my calculation is bad, if possible it would also be good to sync up the inworld units with meters, but that can be the next step. I have the shape of a building and looking at it in leaflet with a geojson layer it looks like this:

[image: Building shape in leaflet geojson]

However, when I am using the Mercator projection from here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/how-to-convert-lat-long-to-meters-using-mercator-projection-in-c
like this:

```
func latlngToMeters(lat, lng):
var sm_a = 6378137.0
lat = deg2rad(lat)
lng = deg2rad(lng)

var x = sm_a * lng
var y = sm_a * log((sin(lat) + 1) / cos(lat))

return Vector2(x, y)
```

Then display it I get this:

[image: Same building shape in godot]

The way I show it is that I get the first point, that is the initalize point, do the projection on it. Then I go tough every single point, the first one becomes (0, 0) then the rest are the offset from the initpoint.

As I wrote before, I think it is some scaling factor I am missing or can it be that I have misunderstood how Mercator works? Any help is appreciated! I have tried to use a c# library (DotSpatial.Projections) but they gave the same error as here.

Comment: There is plenty of info if you do a simple web search "mercator projection distortion"

Comment: @jdweng Yes, there is information about it but can't find any code example showing how to fix it. If you can find that, can you please link it?

Comment: Matlab is always good at these types of problems : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9696-geodetic-transformations?s_tid=srchtitle_mercator%20correction_2

Comment: I have no doubt matlab is good at this, the problem is I need a solution for this in gdscript or C# for this godot project. The buildingshape comes from an API and the clinet, godot, will have to display it.

Comment: REad following : https://www.quora.com/Wouldnt-a-solution-to-correcting-distortion-from-the-Mercator-projection-be-to-first-project-using-Mercator-and-then-compressing-the-map-so-that-the-places-further-from-equator-get-compressed-more?force_isolation=true

Comment: It did not really help me, can you explain?

Comment: The reason why people use Mercator maps is the compass direction is correct, but the lines are distorted.  When direction isn't important and you do not want distortion the recommendation is to use Gall-Peters.  You can't have your cake and pie too.